# How to speed up LIMIT & OFFSET query in a big database

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table which can contain up to billions rows

```
CREATE TABLE "Log4DataUsb" (
"Time" integer primary key not null ,
"Microseconds" integer ,
"Current" integer ,
"Voltage" integer )
```

Usually a user will want to query the data within a specific range, for example `Time <= 123456789 and Time >= 0`, because this may return billions rows, I want to segment the rows and only return a batch each time, like `LIMIT 10,000`, `LIMITE 10,000 OFFSET X` until it reaches the end of this time-range query.

I notice that when the number of rows goes up, this query can be quite slow, executing the queries below will take seconds even though I just want to move to the next batch.

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Time <= 123456789 and Time >= 0 LIMIT 10,000`

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Time <= 123456789 and Time >= 0 LIMIT 10,000 OFFSET 10,0000`

If the database is supposed to have 2 billion rows in total, is there any way it can largely increase the query performance?

Comment: Could you show us your indexes?

Comment: Don't use `OFFSET`. See discussion at https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page for a better approach.

Comment: `If the database is supposed to have 2 billion rows in total` that's almost 70 years of log data, are you sure it'll get that large? At that scale, you might consider using a [better database](https://www.postgresql.org/) with [proper time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-datetime.html) and employing [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html). I can't replicate a slow down in your queries.

Comment: I stored the data from sensors, they stream in high speed, usually it just takes two weeks to generate 1 billion rows. Not sure if I have set any index, I only set "Time" to be the primary key.

Comment: @Shawn the link is helpful, but if I want to support both in-order-query and skip-page-query, is there any good solution?

Comment: Are the `Time` column values contiguous without break, or can it have gaps?  Are rows ever deleted to create gaps, even if original data is contiguous?

Comment: If greater time is spent processing a batch than it takes to retrieve the next batch, consider *asynchronous retrieval* of the next batch.  This can be done in conjunction with other optimization techniques.

Comment: `Time` can have gaps since the sensor sampling rate may change, but the rows will never be deleted, so the coming rows always have greater `Time` compared to the previous.